# Combine CSS3 transforms keeping the reference system

Tags: html, css

With this CSS3 transform:

```
transform: translateX(100px)
```

An element is moved to the right 100 px.

With this one:

```
transform: rotate(180deg)
```

The element is rotated 180 degrees.

But if both are combined:

```
transform: rotate(180deg) translateX(100px)
```

The element is rotated 180 degrees and moved to the LEFT. Because the reference system of the transform is linked to the element and not to the webpage. Is there any way to combine transforms keeping the reference system of the webpage?

Comment: I think no, because the transformation of the reference system can be very powerful. I'd assume, that changing the order of the transformations will also change the behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, it was enough, changing the order of the transform statements:

```
transform: translateX(100px) rotate(180deg)
```

This way, the element was rotated and still moved from the right.
(Chrome)