# Why my css3 hover effect doesn't work in SVG?

Tags: css, animation, svg, svg-animate

I created this SVG and put in some inline CSS to create a hover effect but it doesn't work. The dashed circle doesn't move and rotate, it only changes opacity. In addition, there's no transition on mouse out like normal css transition. How can I fix this ?

```
.wrap:hover .dash {
   opacity: 0.2;
   transform: rotate(90deg);
   -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
   transform: translateX(10px);
   -webkit-transform: translateX(10px);
   transform-origin: 50% 50%;
   -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
   transition: 0.3s linear;
}
```

The link to my code fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7s4vszu3/1/

Comment: Each "transform" is overriding the one above it - you'll want to combine them - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18843374/combine-css3-transforms-keeping-the-reference-system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here:

First, your `transition` and `transform-origin` should be set without the hover selector. This is the reason you weren't seeing the proper transition on mouse out.
Second, you need to include both your transformations in the same rule, so that one doesn't overwrite the other.  In your code, your `translate` is overwriting your `rotate`.

Here's what it should look like:

```
.wrap .dash {
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transition: transform 1s linear, opacity 1s linear;
}

.wrap:hover .dash {
    opacity: 0.2;
    transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(10px);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(10px);
}
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/unc3re9b/

Comment: Thanks, however, when I move the mouse outside, the dashed circle doesn't revert back to its original state, how to fix that ?

Comment: You mean that's the case in the jsfiddle I provided?  It's working for me.

Comment: When on mouse out, the dashed circle reverts its opacity back to 1, but remain the same position, how can I make it move back to the original position when the mouse is out ?

Comment: You're saying that that is happening on this page too? http://jsfiddle.net/unc3re9b/

Comment: Yeah, happening on your jsfiddle, i'm using lasted Chorme

Comment: Unfortunately, it may just be a browser compatibility issue.  The way that SVG and CSS transforms play together is still rather inconsistent from browser to browser.  You may want to consider using SVG animations instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64756/discussion-between-casey-rule-and-user25808).